# Magento Upgrade - Is there any DB change after magento upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

I have done Magento version 1.9.1.1 upgrade to Magento 1.9.3.8. in local machine.

Now, is there any new DB changes in my **local machine DB**?

I am planing to a add files only to **LIVE** server. Is this works fine ?

I am not sure about these.

**Can any one guide me regarding this ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are more-than-likely database changes.

After deploying your code, `clear the Magento cache`, `log out of the admin and then back in`, and `refresh the front-end of the site`.

That should be enough for the SQL Update scripts contained within the update to fire.

Comment: Means, I can add local Files only to live server.

Thanks for reply.

Comment: I have completed the Magento upgrade to v 1.9.3.8 few days ago by only adding upgraded Magento files from my local machine to LIVE server. There was some issues but website is working fine now. Thanks for guidance.